# How to multiply a variable with a variable?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to do a project where I have to multiply a variable with a variable, and I get an error.

```
sprite = codesters.Sprite("person1")
choice = sprite.ask("What is the thing you want to log?")
my_var=choice
choice2 = sprite.ask("amount of times you " + my_var + " a day?")
my_var2=choice2
AmountPerYear=choice2*365
choice3=sprite.ask("How much money per day")
MoneyPerYear=choice3*365
Choice3= sprite.ask("How long does it take to " + my_var + " in seconds")
my_var3=Choice3
TimePerDay = my_var3 * my_var2
```

That last line does not work:

```
Oops! can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' on line: 12 
  TimePerDay = my_var3 * my_var2
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, passing input into Python takes your input in the form of a `string`. Because of this, your program is attempting to multiply two strings, which isn't allowed, such as `"5" * "6"`. You want to convert your values to `int` types before multiplying, so it can properly carry out the operation like `5 * 6`:

```
TimePerDay = int(my_var3) * int(my_var2)
```

You may want to also check though beforehand that the user is inputting a proper int input

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `my_var2` and `my_var3` are strings. They *might* be  strings that contain a number, but this is not guaranteed. Suppose your user puts in `apple` and `pear`. What is `apple x pear`? It's meaningless.

You need to 'cast' the variables to integers. Try this:

`TimePerday = int(my_var3) * int(my_var2)`

This will work if the strings contain numbers, e.g.  `int('2') = 2`, but if they do not, e.g. `int('apple')`, you will get an error.